# If $X,Y$ have $n,m$ elements, there are $m(m-1)...(m-n+1)$ injective functions $f: X \to Y$.

Tags: functions

If $X,Y$ have $n,m$ elements, there are $m(m-1)...(m-n+1)$ injective functions $f: X  \to Y$.

By induction. If $n=0$, then we have one unique function from the empty set to $Y$.

How do I relate this back to $m(m-1)...(m-n+1)$ injective functions? If $n=0$, then we have $m-n+1 = m+1$ injective functions?

Edit:
The inductive step I'm also a bit confused on.

To give an injective function $f$, we specify $f(a) \in Y$ (m possibilities) and an injective function $X \setminus \{a\}$ to $Y \setminus {f(a)}$$

The domain has $n-1$ elements and the codomain has $m-1$ elements. Thus there are $(m-1)(m-2) \cdots m-1-(n-1)+1 = m-n+1$

Is this right?

Comment: The product on the right is supposed to have $n$ terms.  When $n=0$, this gives an empty product, which is, by convention, $1$, just an empty sum is conventionally $0$.

Comment: There are $\binom{m}{n}$ subsets $U$ of $Y$ of size $n,$ and $n!$ bijections $X\to U.$

Comment: The formal way to write that product is $$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (m-k).$$ When $n=0,$ there are no terms in the product, and an empty product is $1.$ $\prod_{k=0}^{-1}$ doesn't mean we take the cases $k=0,k=-1$, it means we take no terms. A similar thing is true for sums: $$\sum_{k=0}^{-1} f(k)=0$$ for any function $f.$

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you, do you mind answering my edit? It's on the same proof.

Comment: The idea is right, but you could write it up more clearly.  You never actually arrive at $m(m-1)\cdots(m-n+1)$